Pass a variable through .ajaxComplete
I have an number of places where I paired a static div with content with an editable field to update that content on a drupal10 site. Using $(div).load(url), I've got it working on a single basis like so:
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container form .form-submit').click(function () {
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (typeof settings !== 'undefined' && settings.extraData && settings.extraData._drupal_ajax) {
             $('.targetdiv').load(location.href + " .targetdiv > *");
         }   
       }
     );
  });
})(jQuery);

However, I have pages where I have multiple instances, and I'm struggling to get a variable to trigger after the .ajaxComplete. I've also tried variations of $(this), but I believe the ajax process breaks the focus so it doesn't work. I need this to work so only the refreshdiv in the set associated with the click reloads.
I've got this far:
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var targetID = $('.container').data('id');
        $(document).on('click', '.editfield' + targetID + ' form .form-submit', function(){
        });
        // Listening for AJAX completion after button click
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('ajax complete');
        // Check if the AJAX request is from Drupal
        if (typeof settings !== 'undefined' && settings.extraData && settings.extraData._drupal_ajax) {
            $(".container .refreshdiv").addClass(targetID);
            $('.targetID').load(location.href + " .targetID > *");
         }
     });
  });
})(jQuery);

But in this second case, the variable targetID doesn't carry through the ajax process. I've also tried placing the variable after .ajaxComplete, but that comes up blank too.
I expect I need to pass the variable through the .ajaxComplete function somehow. What am I missing?

I see the problem you are facing is scoping issue with the targetID variable inside the ajaxComplete function.
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Function to handle click event on form submit button
    function handleFormSubmit() {
      var targetID = $(this).closest('.container').data('id');
      $(this).closest('.container').data('targetID', targetID);
    }

    // Click event handler for form submit button
    $('.container form .form-submit').on('click', handleFormSubmit);

    // AJAX complete event handler
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
      console.log('ajax complete');
      if (typeof settings !== 'undefined' && settings.extraData && settings.extraData._drupal_ajax) {
        var targetID = $('.container').data('targetID');
        if (targetID) {
          $('.editfield' + targetID + ' .refreshdiv').load(location.href + ' .refreshdiv');
        }
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);



Ah, this feels close, but it's not working. A few issues: 1) I notice the ajax complete console message comes up before the xhr finishes loading. I added a console.log before and after your "if (targetID)" but neither are registering. 2) the refresh div is separate from the editfield, so I adjusted accordingly, but it's still not triggering.

Also, are the two "var targetID" calls intentional? I may have read that one calls the variable again and updates it after the Ajax completes - is that what is going on here? If so, why are they defined differently?

OK, I've debugged this every way I can, but the second targetID variable is still coming up undefined.

This code temporarily add the element's class name with the value of the targetID variable
$(".container .refreshdiv").addClass(targetID);

This code takes the html from its own url and puts it in an element with the class name 'targetID', not the value of the variable targetID
$('.targetID').load(location.href + " .targetID > *");

You should change the code to:
var targetIDClass = '.' + targetID;    
$(targetIDClass).load(location.href + ' ' + targetIDClass  + '> *');

Note: this code temporarily adds the class to the element, when it loads the data from the url I'm not sure if this class is available from the data result
$(".container .refreshdiv").addClass(targetID);


Ok, I'm starting to see the problem with the addClass, so I hardcoded classes into the required divs to test. Unfortunately, var targetIDClass = '.' + targetID; still doesn't recognize the targetID variable from before .ajaxComplete and it doesn't trigger. If i remove targetID and put in a fixed class, it updates, but the content is empty.

Should you give me your site url ?

Unfortunately, the site is still in dev. I'll have to find a workaround.
